# Can't run app downloaded from github

Tags: xcode

I have downloaded the example from github, but i can't run because of run option disable how to run it?..
please see screenshot of my app[image]

Answer (score 1):

The scheme is set to a library build. 2 Buttons to the right of the play button is this box with AOModelStatus. If this is an app, you can select a different scheme.

As far as I can see, this is no app, but a framework. So no option to run it.

Answer (score 1):

This example that you download it's not an app, it's a framework.

Frameworks don't run on devices or simulators.